# U-SQL in on premises environment

Tags: azure, u-sql, bigdata

I've just read amazing article about U-SQL in msdn magazine.

U-SQL is great tool to analyze big data in microsoft azure.

However, it is possible to use it in non-cloud environment, e.g. in SQL Server hosted on premises?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U-SQL currently is not available in SQL Server. Best is to ask the SQL Server team if they have plans ;).

You can use U-SQL locally on your development box when using the local mode in the Azure Data Lake Tools in Visual Studio.

If you would like to see U-SQL for production workloads on an on-prem system, please file your request with a scenario at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Comment: Link is broken, it leads to a bing.com search page

Comment: @MotKohn: the Microsoft user feedback system has been revamped. Please find the new Microsoft user feedback system such as http://aka.ms/SynapseIdeas and https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0. Since we are not developing the ADLA service anymore, there is no ADLA specific feedback system available at the moment.